# Buscar registro desde un formulario en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Necesito colocar un campo de búsqueda en un formulario y si encuentra el registro en la base de datos complete los datos del formulario recuperados desde la base de datos, logre realizar la búsqueda en el método index, que me muestra los datos en una tabla, pero yo quiero realizar lo mismo pero para un formulario, estoy trabajando en laravel 5.5.

Por ejemplo si ingreso el rut del doctor y ya existe, debería recuperar los datos de la base de datos, en caso contrario indicar que no esta registrado.

Desde ya gracias a quien pueda ayudarme

[image: formulario de busqueda]

Answer (score 1):

Debes crear un api en laravel y recuperar los datos mediante ajax.

Para crear el api:

Debes crear la ruta en el archivo `api.php`, por ejemplo:

**Ruta**

```
 Route::get("doctor/{rut}", "DoctorController@getInfoDoctor");

//Metodo en controlador

//Usando eloquent

public function getInfoDoctor($rut){

    $doctor = App\Doctor::whereRut($rut)->first();


    if(isset($doctor)){

       return response()->json("doctor" => $doctor);

    }else{

        return "No se enceontraron resultados" ;

   }

}
```

Despues de realizar el anterior backend debes hacer la llamada ajax con javascript cuando el usuario pulse el boton de buscar de rut.

Asi con el objeto $doctor, puedes obtener toda su informacion.

Comment: se garadece tu aporte pero el usuario no muestra avance alguno en código por lo cual es dificil ayudarle de acuerdo a lo que realmente necesita

Comment: además tu respsuesta no responde lo que el usuario pregunta ya que el requiere llenar un formlario con la información provista y tu solo estas retornando un json

Comment: Entiendo que solo retorna un json, solo falta la parte de AJAX con JavaScript para mostrar los datos en el formulario. Me parece que la pregunta es clara, lo que escribí le puede dar una ayuda al usuario.